# Join two JSON file in resource view calendar

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, calendar

Here is my code for full calendar with resource view:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: false,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today myCustomButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceDay,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        defaultView: 'month',
        resources: {url: 'json/resources.json'}, <--- resource.json file path
        events: {url: 'json/events.json'}  <--- events.json file path
    });

});
```

Output:

[Output for event page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csNGI.png)

[Output for resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Y9V.png)

Now the problem is "this is for full calendar plugin with resource view" when I run the code it fetches the details for events and displays but when I click resource button it doesn't display anything!